# Select menu options treated as links in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, drop-down-menu

I have a normal html select menu. Firefox treats the options as links, but IE does not. This means my CSS code to alter links on hover is messing up the select menu in Firefox. How can I stop this?

The select menu simplified is:

```
<Select name='country' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
<option selected value='1'>USA</option>
<option value='2'>UK</option>
</Select>
```

The CSS simplified is:

```
#rightnavigation {
font: 12pt Arial,geneva,sans-serif;
}
#rightnavigation :link {color: green; font: 10pt Arial,geneva,sans-serif;}
#rightnavigation :visited {color: red; font: 10pt Arial,geneva,sans-serif;}
#rightnavigation :hover {color: orange; font: 10pt Arial,geneva,sans-serif;}
```

When I move the mouse onto the menu, all the options resize to font 10 and turn orange in Firefox, instead of staying black like in IE.

I tried creating a class and applying it to each option, but this only worked on the non-selected options.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your selectors to affect only links:

```
#rightnavigation a:link {color: green; font: 10pt Arial,geneva,sans-serif;}
#rightnavigation a:visited {color: red; font: 10pt Arial,geneva,sans-serif;}
#rightnavigation a:hover {color: orange; font: 10pt Arial,geneva,sans-serif;}
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realise these actions were not already limited to links. (I'm too new to upvote your answer, but thanks again).

Comment: But you should be able to select it as the correct answer by clicking on the check mark under the up-down voting.